# Xamarin cross plataform 9-patch like solution

Tags: xamarin

Is there a way to work with stretchable images like 9-patch for android or *resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets* for IOS on all platforms?

Answer (score 1):

In traditional Xamarin development you need to deal with the platform native image capabilities. The platforms don't share any image format and you wouldn't want to handle images platform agnostic anyways as the native classes are optimized for memory and performance. You would lose every  benefit of those optimization.

In Xamarin.Forms you would need to look for a 3rd party library like NGraphics or [NControl](https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl) maybe...

See this excellent article about [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paid library http://forms9patch.com i have used it myself and it is pretty solid

You can turn any image to 9patch in crossplaform manner:

```
var image2 = new Forms9Patch.Image () {
    Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MyDemoApp.Resources.Images.redribbon.png"),
    CapInsets = new Thickness(23, 0, 110, 0),
}
```

[image]

EDIT: Note that a Forms9Patch license is not required to use Forms9Patch.ImageSource. So you can use Forms9Patch.ImageSource using this library for free

Comment: Forms9Patch is a FREE (MIT License) library.